# dynamically created wpf control doesn't work the same as the control it is based on

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, controls

Continuing on from my previous question [create dynamically complex controls in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338592/create-dynamically-complex-controls-in-wpf)
My code was based on a code project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1) on movable and resizable shapes

Originally I had created a control that was resizable in my xaml, and had a problem creating a copy of the control in code.
Now, that problem has been solved, but I have added the ability to move my resizable control, which works perfectly, but the copy of it created in code will only resize and not move, and I am at a loss to see why.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MazeBuilder.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:MazeBuilder"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- MoveThumb Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- ResizeDecorator Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid>
            <s:ResizeThumb Height="3" Cursor="SizeNS" Margin="0 -4 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="3" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="-4 0 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="3" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="0 0 -4 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Height="3" Cursor="SizeNS" Margin="0 0 0 -4"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Margin="-6 -6 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNESW" Margin="0 -6 -6 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNESW" Margin="-6 0 0 -6"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Margin="0 0 -6 -6"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Designer Item Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <Control Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"/>
            <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll"/>                
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" MouseDown="LayoutRoot_MouseDown" MouseMove="LayoutRoot_MouseMove">
    <Popup Name="PopupEsales" Placement="Right" IsEnabled="True" IsOpen="False" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView Height="145" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="lvSalesPersonIdSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sales Persons Id" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SPID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Popup>
    <Menu Height="23" IsMainMenu="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="640">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New Maze"  Click="New_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Load Maze" Click="Load_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save Maze" Click="Save_Click"  />

        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Tools">
            <MenuItem Header="Show"  Click="ShowTools_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <ContentControl  Width="130"
                MinWidth="50"
                Height="130"
                MinHeight="50"
                Canvas.Top="150"
                Canvas.Left="470"
                Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </ContentControl>


    <Canvas.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
    </Canvas.Background>


</Canvas>
```

This is the control I am trying to duplicate:

```
            <ContentControl  Width="130"
            MinWidth="50"
            Height="130"
            MinHeight="50"
            Canvas.Top="150"
            Canvas.Left="470"
            Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
       IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</ContentControl>
```

And here is my code to create a new instance of the control:

```
   ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
    ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate();
    object rs = this.Resources["DesignerItemTemplate"];
    ct = (ControlTemplate)rs;
    cc.Template = ct;
    cc.Height = 10;
    cc.Width = 10;
    cc.Content = new Rectangle { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0,0,255)) };
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(cc);
    Canvas.SetLeft(cc, 300);
    Canvas.SetTop(cc, 300);
```

This creates a control that is resizable, but it won't move at all, and the cursor doesn't change when you mouse over it like it does for the one created in xaml. As I believe I have assigned the correct Resource, I can't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Why do you create a controltemplate object (cc) and then replace this object with the resource "DesignerItemTemplate"?  Should you be setting ct.Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting `IsHiteTestVisible = false` on your `Rectangle`. That is the problem, because your `ContentPresenter` is on top of the `MoveThumb` in your template. I'm not sure what the `MoveThumb` looks like, but if it is just a transparent rectangle, I'd put that on top of the `ContentPresenter` so you don't have to worry about setting `IsHitTestVisible` on all the children you add.

Comment: Cheers Abe, that is exactly my problem. Thanks very much, I just feel like a beginner again doing this WPF stuff.

Comment: NP, it is pretty confusing at first. But once it clicks, it does become much easier.